# When do one have to actually calculate the net charge of an amino acid?

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry

When the pH and the pKa levels differ by 2 or more you don't need to calculate the net charge. What you do then is to just count the negative and positive charge and add them up. 
When pH=pKa you also don't need to calculate, because you get half of the different types.

BUT what about if we want to know the net charge for an amino acid where one of the groups have an pKa value of 4,25 , when the pH is
a) 4,0  , b)5 , c) 5,5 and d)6
Do you have to calculate it for all of these? Can you say that since a) is pretty close to the pKa we consider them the same, or that since d) is pretty close to being 2 units more, we can just say that and make it easier? And is there even really a point in calculating for c) when it's more than 1 pH unit over?

My question is basically: where do I draw the line?

Comment: You draw the line where the error is acceptable for your application. Without knowing what you want to know the charge for, it's hard to give much more of an answer than that. N.B. many software packages like [MarvinSketch](https://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/sketch/index.php) will easily calculate the average charge and even give you species distributions for different pH values.

Comment: Your question hardly makes sense to others, because you provide your thinking and a fragment of the info in the question, and there's no sign of any real question. Please see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and edit your question to include a real question.